# Small Logic Editor Text

Tags: interface

While I was working on a game my logic editor tab got very tiny and I can barely see it! How do I undo or fix this? I am new to blender so I didn't want to really mess with anything yet until I know what it all does. So if someone could explain it to me that would be great. I also have join.me if anyone needs to check my screen for it. Thank you.

Comment: Did you use the scroll wheel of your mouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> and drag left or right, or up and down to increase or decrease the size of the interface.

This works on many (but not all) of the 'areas' in blender, like the Graph Editor, Image Editor or the Properties area. It also works in the 3D view Toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>) and the Properties toolbar (<kbd>N</kbd>).

Comment: If the answer solved your problem then please check the tick icon next to my answer, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

With the mouse in the Logic Editor, Node Editor, UV Image Editor, Timeline, Graph Editor, Dope Sheet, NLA Editor, Video Sequence Editor, or Movie Clip Editor you can simply scroll with the <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> to zoom in or out.